# Как сделать поиск пути ,но используется процедурная генерация в unity2D?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я разрабатывал игру с видом сверху, сделал процедурную генерацию карты, но столкнулся с проблемой поиска пути для врага.

Использую версию 2020.3.24f1

Как сделать оптимальный поиск пути для данной задачи?

P.s Заранее спасибо!!!

Comment: Алгоритмов поиска пути вагон и маленькая тележка, да и в юнити наверняка уже есть библиотека для этого

Comment: https://youtu.be/jvtFUfJ6CP8

Comment: Алгоритм A* (a-star) самый оптимальный.